# Scala parser combinator - almost there!

Tags: regex, parsing, scala

After [I solved the initial problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460662/having-trouble-with-scalas-repsep-as-seen-in-parser-combinators), I now believe I have parsed everything, and it now seems to be choking on the very end of the input:

```
Failure: [9.1] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `' found

^
```

Um, it is finding no characters at the very end.  Should I append my own "\z" EOF somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really solve your original problem. See my answer, where I cover this problem. Basically, there's a `\r\n` at the end of the file -- which is taken to be a separator -- so it expects another repetition.