# Grab every character in String until a specified word Scala Regex

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I'm new to Scala and trying to parse a very simple String and get every character until encountering "--batch" with the following String parser:

```
def getEntireMetaData : Parser[EntireMetaData] = """(?s).+?(?=--batch)""".r ^^ { EntireMetaData}
```

And I call it as the following:

```
val batchRequest: String = "POST /service/$batch HTTP/1.1 \nHost: host \n +
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b\n \n" +
"--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b "

implicit val p = parser.getEntireMetaData
parser.parseAll(p, batchRequest) match {
  case result: parser.Success[_] => println(result.get) 
  case result: parser.NoSuccess => fail(result.toString) 
}
```

which gives me the error

```
[7.1] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `-' found

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b

^
```

The following is what I want my parser to match:

```
"POST /service/$batch HTTP/1.1 \nHost: host \n +
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b\n \n"
```

Please help me sort this out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b`, misses a closing quote.

Comment: Updated the input string. The error still remains the same. @Avinash Raj

Comment: Have a look at a similar issue at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5460948/3832970. Perhaps, you need to add whitespace support to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have a few different issues:

1. You are not actually catching your match
2. You are missing a " after `\nHost: host \n`

Overall, the following expression does what you want: `(?s)(.+?)(?=--batch)`

On the other hand, you hardly need a regex for this:

`batchRequest.substring(0, batchRequest.indexOf("--batch"))`

gets you:

`POST /service/$batch HTTP/1.1 
Host: host 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b`

You can also check if `indexOf` returns -1 before of course.

Comment: 1_ that is the multiline enable option (?s) not a character match
2_ (?=--batch) supposed do that?
3_ using multiline option
4_ you're right. 

How do I use the output of `batchRequest.substring(0, batchRequest.indexOf("--batch"))` in a parser?

Comment: Interesting. I had to look that up, I always passed flags directly and never used embedded flag expression before. Ok, so 1 and 3 are actually the same thing, solved. For 2, just put a normal parenthesis around the text you want, this will catch that group: `(.+?)` followed by `(?=--batch)` which is a non-catching group. As I mentioned above. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer...

Comment: As for the parser. You can always create a custom one around this code I guess. But my point is that you probably don't need that extra complexity if you just need to extract that piece of a string.